# Ruby On Rails Model Relationships and Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, associations, models

I have Two models named Rounds and Teams, Each round has 2 teams team 1 and team 2 and their respective scores like team_1_score and team_2_score. Team has many rounds. I am aware of how to tackle multiple associations using class and foreign keys from rounds table to Teams table. What's been confusing for me is, how to handle their respective scores. For example Is there any way to get 1st team score like first_team.rounds.where('some condition').score. Can I use such prototype to get first team score and if second team object is used then it returns second team score. I am looking forward for any sort of help. That would be really great. Thank you

Comment: Kindly tell me the reason, when you down vote it. Because I have done my best to get around it. That's why I am asking here this question. To me it's a good question. All I am saying is let me know where I went wrong instead of just doing down vote. Thanks.

Comment: could you show your schema.rb?

Comment: Actually I have made wholy picture of the database in my mind. I kind of stuck in this problem. So Right now I do not have schema.rb.

Comment: so you want to get a teams collective score from multiple rounds or just the score from one round?

Comment: Just the score from one round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your models

```
class Round < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teams
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rounds
end
```

To get a specific teams score on a specific round I would do:

```
@team = Team.find(id: params[:team_id])

score =  Round.where(team_id: @team.id).team_1_score
```

Assuming you do this in a controller where the params are present, otherwise just find the team and round by their id's and do

I'd suggest you use a has_many :through relationship though. This would create a whole new table where you could query records by round ID and team ID and then return the teams score.

Comment: sure thing! Would you mind accepting the answer please?